# Users cannot connect to The Ship dedicated server

Tags: hosting, source-engine, the-ship

I am attempting to run a dedicated server for The Ship on my Ubuntu VPS.
The server seems to start and run just fine, but nobody can connect to it - any attempts simply result in a timeout.

To start the server, I used this command:

```
$ ./srcds_run -game ship
```

And this is the output:
    Auto detecting CPU
    Using SSE2 Optimised binary.
    Auto-restarting the server on crash

```
Console initialized.
Attempted to create unknown entity type event_queue_saveload_proxy!
Game.dll loaded for "The Ship"
CSoundEmitterSystem::AddSoundsFromFile:  No such file scripts/game_sounds_single_player.txt
CSoundEmitterSystem::AddSoundsFromFile:  No such file scripts/game_sounds_vo_tutorial.txt
maxplayers set to 1
Unknown command "ex/"
Unknown command "yautoexec.cfg"
Unknown command "y"
Unknown command "startunuel"
Unknown command "startupmvevel"
Unknown command "startupmenvel"
Unknown command "startupmenuel"
Unknown command "startupmenu"
Network: IP ***, mode MP, dedicated Yes, ports 27015 SV / 27005 CL
```

(I replaced the IP with *s, that was deliberate)

Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT:**

I have looked into my server's IPTables configuration, and this is what my IPTables looks like:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:27015
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:27015

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http
```

And I have been told that this should make it work, in terms of port redirection.
Even so, I have tried running the server using sudo, and it does not have any effect.
Therefore, I think it isn't an issue with my server.

Comment: Did you redirect the ports?

Comment: Also "maxplayers set to 1" was this what you intended? You said players and not player or me.

Comment: @ardaozkal, I did notice that, but **nobody** can connect.

Comment: @ardaozkal, also, if it is a plain VPS, is port redirection a necessary thing? I did not change any port configuration myself.

Comment: Yes, doing port redirection on a VPS is important. Probably firewall is enabled.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/360236/how-can-i-redirect-a-port-number-on-linux

Comment: Also I flagged this (Blatantly off-topic) as it is a firewall/port redirection issue. You should ask on askubuntu or serverfault, however, this question is answered multiple times at those websites, I commented a question that answers this too.

Comment: @ardaozkal, I've added some more information above, I'm not sure if it is actually a problem with my VPS or its configuration.